# how to render list of children class in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, rubygems

**Hi there**,

I'm starting to use Rails through a little project. All the main things are between some Doctors, patients and consultations.
I'm learning with a book to start my application and for now, it works well but i still need help for little twists!

For example, once a doctor is created, i can create a consultation but my consultation needs a patient and i don't understand how to render a list of patients in the creation of my consultation.

Does someone have a clue?

PS: This is my code

=> DOCTOR

```
require 'digest'
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :birthdate, :birthplace, :city, :country, :firstname, :id_card_no, :lastname, :mail, :password, :secu_no, :street, :street_number, :zip
attr_accessor :password
validates :birthdate, :birthplace, :city, :country, :firstname, :lastname, :id_card_no, :secu_no, :street, :street_number, :zip, :presence=>true

validates :id_card_no,:secu_no, :uniqueness=>true

validates :street_number, :zip, :numericality=>true

validates :password, :confirmation => true,
            :length => { :within => 4..20 },
            :presence => true,
            :if => :password_required?

validates :mail, :uniqueness => true,
                :length => { :within => 5..50 },
                :format => { :with => /^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i }

has_and_belongs_to_many :offices
has_and_belongs_to_many :specialities
has_and_belongs_to_many :secretaries
has_many :consultations

default_scope order('doctors.lastname')

before_save :encrypt_new_password

    def self.authenticate(email, password)
        user = find_by_email(email)
        return user if user && user.authenticated?(password)
    end
    def authenticated?(password) 
        self.hashed_password == encrypt(password)
    end

protected
    def encrypt_new_password
        return if password.blank?
        self.hashed_password = encrypt(password) 
    end
    def password_required?
        hashed_password.blank? || password.present?
    end
    def encrypt(string) 
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string)
    end

end
```

=> PATIENT

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :birthdate, :birthplace, :city, :country, :firstname, :id_card_no, :job, :lastname, :secu_no, :street, :street_number, :zip

validates :birthdate, :birthplace, :city, :country, :firstname, :lastname, :id_card_no, :secu_no, :street, :street_number, :zip, :presence=>true

validates :id_card_no,:secu_no, :uniqueness=>true

validates :street_number, :zip, :numericality=>true

has_many :consultations

default_scope order('patients.lastname')


end
```

=> CONSULTATION

```
class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :date, :hour

validates :date, :hour, :presence=>true

belongs_to :patient
belongs_to :doctor
has_one :patient_description
has_one :consultation_file
has_and_belongs_to_many :illnesses
has_and_belongs_to_many :symptoms

end
```

Thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look into a "collection_select" on the "patient_id" column of the consultation.

Comment: Yes Thanks, i found some example there if someone has the same prob => http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) for this, as it "understands" your fields and e.g. creates select boxes for associations or date pickers for dates automatically:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @consultation do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :date %>
    <%= f.input :hour %>
    <%= f.input :doctor %>
    <%= f.input :patient %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
    <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, this is not a pure Rails solution and needs an additional Gem. I am not sure if that is okay for your training purpose.